# Excel Changes sheets when I enter value into any cell

Tags: vba, excel

Once again I need your brilliant minds. I am working on a rather larger workbook for work and, now that i'm nearing it's completion, it has started doing something very strange. Anytime I enter a value into an unlocked cell in 18 of the 21 sheets, it takes me to a different sheet. The only code that is similar across the 18 sheets and does not exist in the other 3 is shown below. What this code is doing is checking a cell within the sheet to see if it changes to know whether or not the sheet should be hidden. This cell is tied to a "calculations sheet" where there are check boxes that users can use to decide if they need that sheet or not. If you see something in this code that may cause this to change sheets, I'd love to hear it. I'm only about a week from rolling this out test users and about a month from taking it live. If it would be helpful to see the whole workbook, I'd be happy to get that to you too.
Thanks!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Static oldval
    If Range("CG1").Value <> oldval Then
        oldval = Range("CG1").Value
        Sheets("CS Personnel").Visible = False
            Select Case Range("CG1").Value
            Case Is = False:
                Sheets("CS Personnel").Visible = True
            End Select
    End If
```

Comment: I'd suggest putting Breakpoints into all worksheet events (worksheet_change, worksheet_calculate etc.) in this problematic sheet code, enter a value into that cell that's causing the problem and step through the code. You will find the line. With confidence, it's not in the worksheet_calculate code you posted. Maybe somewhere below the last `End If`, but I can't see :)

Comment: Everything after `oldval= Range("CG1").Value` could be replaced with one line: `Sheets("CS Personnel").Visible = Not oldval`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Tim Williams Thanks for making the code more straight forward. I changed of them as you suggested and for some reason it is working OK now.
Cheers!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Static oldval
If Range("CG1").Value <> oldval Then
    oldval = Range("CG1").Value
        Sheets("CS Personnel").Visible = Not oldval
    End If
End Sub
```